# Prometheus query to get last 30 days each offset by n days to use in function

Tags: prometheus, promql

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a threshold that would effectively be the 95th percentile for this same hour/minute/... for the last n days.

For example I would like a query that can do the following

```
http_requests_total offset 1d
http_requests_total offset 2d
http_requests_total offset 3d
http_requests_total offset ...
```

In a manner such that the results could be used in an aggregate function like sum, min, max, stddev etc. But I can't figure out how to accomplish this, I suppose if it's my only option I could just list every single query and offset up to 30 but I don't know how to do more than 1 of those in the same query.

So something like (this doesn't work obviously but it's what comes to mind when thinking of what I know about the language)

```
statsfuncton((http_requests_total offset [1d:1d:30d])[1h])
```

Once I have that I can use basic operators and things to compare to a query of current metrics.